# Zendframework 2 on cPanel

Tags: zend-framework2, cpanel

I'm trying to install zf2 on cpanel in a subdomain. www.domain.ro/test.
I extracted zip file in directory public_html/test.
So I have in test/zf folder structure:

```
bin
library
resources
composer.json
...
```

in public_html/test I have the php.ini with include_path:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/cPanelUsername/public_html/test/zf/library"
```

For testing if zf2 is installed correctly, I create a zend-test.php with lines:

```
<?
phpinfo();
require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';
$mail=new Zend_Mail();
echo 'it is working';
?>
```

And I have error:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cPanelUsername/public_html/test/zend-test.php on line 3
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/cPanelUsername/public_html/test/zf/library') in /home/cPanelUsername/public_html/test/zend-test.php on line 3
```

Comment: If you are using ZF2 you shouldn't even have a `library` folder, and you shouldn't be using ZF1 specific class names like `Zend_Mail`. If you are really using ZF1, then check to see whether `Zend/Mail.php` exists in your library folder.

Comment: Like the title, I'm trying to use ZF2. You right I shouldn't use zend_mail(), but the problem is with require_once Zend/Mail.php, wicth I think it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeded using ZF2_PATH environemnt variable.
In directory public_html/test I create an index.php file with lines:

```
putenv( "ZF2_PATH=/home/cPanelUsername/public_html/test/zf/library");
include "zf/application/public/index.php";
```

And I create application folder in zf folder.
Application folder has structure :

```
config
data
module
public
```

This way the problem was solved. I can use zf2 on cPanel with a subdomain like www.domain.com/test, for testing propose.